# change check box and tick color once selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

im trying change the background color and tick color of a check box once the user has checked the box.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" />
```

eg: once a use is checked i want to make the box blue.

I have been googling for a while but still couldn't get a solution for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the actual checkbox element and the check that shows up when you click it? If so you can't do that with regular css, you'd have to use a js library to completely change the browser element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name=thisBox]').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
           //Code to change checkbox
        }
    });        
});​
```

Comment: CSS and checkbox, radio, and select don't usually jive too well. This plugin would be a decent solution to 'skin' these elements.